# fourier transform of $\operatorname{sinc}$ function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to do the fourier transform of this signal $\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{t}{10}\right)$ where sinc function is defined as $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$.

the transform of this signal according to my studies is: $\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{f}{\frac{1}{10}}\right)$.is right?

Comment: "is it right" - could you show what you did on paper to get your result?

Comment: I had applied rules find in tables in my math book

Comment: Which book? How did you apply said rules? Even if you have the right answer, that's not worth much if your method is faulty.

Comment: In my book I have a formula says: $Asinc(Bt) \to \frac{A}{B}rect\left(\frac{f}{B}\right)$. I applied it as I found it.

Comment: So, why didn't *you* get $\mathrm{rect}(10f)$ as the answer?

Comment: @J.M. I don't think he showed it yet but was rather asking how to do it.

Comment: ops...right!I made mistake writing function but in my paper is right...